# Magento 2.3.4 use system value checkbox disabled not able to uncheck the box

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, configuration, system-configuration, magento2.3.4

Can someone help me out from this issue? I have installed Magento 2.3.4 CE in my local system then I just want to enable the DHL shipping method but I am not able to do that because 'use system value' checkbox itself disabled If I change the store view also no luck.

**Note : not only DHL, all system configurations checkbox disabled.**
[image]

Comment: Do you have an errors in JS console ?

Comment: I saw this message : " JQMIGRATE: Migrate is installed with logging active, version 1.4.1 ". is it affecting ?

Comment: Hello, go to stores->attributes search for example title, open it and try to change its scope to global/store, save flush caches and run reindex, and check it again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uncheck checkbox and change value in admin panel. Still, if you can't able to change from admin panel. Then, you can also change using below command :

```
php bin/magento config:set carriers/dhl/active 1
```

### UPDATE :

open **config.php** file from **app/etc/config.php** location.

Now remove everything from this file except - modules array like below code :

```
return [
'modules' => 
[
'Magento_Store' => 1,
'Magento_AdminNotification' => 1,
...
...
...
],
];
```

then save this file  !!

now after saving this file you need to run below command :

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

php bin/magento setup:di:compile

php bin/magento cache:clean

php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Then logged in to your backend admin panel - and check now configuration are unlocked and able to editable.

**Note : Before do this please take backup of your db and code**

Comment: thanks for your support. I was able to set DHL enable yes but the problem is all configurations checkboxes are locked / disabled. We can not change each and every configuration fields using command instead of setting up the values in Magento Admin. After run the above command it is showing like values set and env.php locked. Because of this env.php file option locked only causing the issue. How can we unlock the configuration checkboxes ?

Comment: Did you executed app:config:dump command ? Maybe it's locked because of that. Not sure, but maybe

Comment: yes I executed app:config:dump command.

Comment: is there any way to unlock them ?

Comment: check my updated answer. But, take backup of your store before execute answer.

Comment: sure I will try this.

Comment: to solve this issue we need to reset app/etc/config.php & app/etc/env.php extra content which is added after ran app:config:dump command by comparing these files with fresh magento files. No need to run the above mentioned commands because if we run 'php bin/magento setup:di:compile' command it will create some problems I faced that